# Formating Phone Numbers in Applescript

Tags: applescript, number-formatting, phone-number, automator

I am trying to create an Automator task that uses an applescript to format a phone number into the format (XXX)XXX-XXXX

```
on clean_number(phoneNumber)
    set newString to {}
    repeat with c in the characters of phoneNumber
        set c to c as text
        if c is not "-" then
            if c is not " " then
                set the end of newString to c
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
    return newString
end clean_number

on run {input, parameters}
    set originalText to clean_number(input) as string
    if length of originalText is 10 then
        set areaCode to items 1 thru 3 of originalText as string
        set localExchange to items 4 thru 6 of originalText as string
        set phoneNumber to items 7 thru end of originalText as string
        set result to "(" & areaCode & ")" & localExchange & "-" & phoneNumber as string
        return result
    end if
end run
```

when I run this I get no result. I have tested out the run function individually and it works. The problem I am getting seems to be in the repeat, because when I try to return c from inside the repeat I get no result

edit:
As iayork recommended I tried running the script through terminal, and it worked! This implies that the problem lies somewhere in the way Automator is handling the script.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**  I believe the problem is with the way Automator takes input.  It is always a list, even if there's one item.  Therefore you need to change your line

```
set originalText to clean_number(input) as string
```

(which works fine with the script editor) to

```
set originalText to clean_number(item 1 of input) as string
```

I don't know how you're invoking your Automator action; I used "Get contents of clipboard" and "Copy to clipboard" to test this.

**Original answer:**
Your script works for me. I suspect that the input phone number is being entered  in such a way that the "length" is not 10; for example, with a comma, or with the parameters getting combined with the input.

If you run

```
osascript test.scpt 1234567890 parameters
```

you should be able to confirm that the script itself is working.  If this still is a problem, check exactly what Automator is passing to the script (I don't know if Automator wants to add some parameters, but if not, you can eliminate that from the on run section for simplicity)

Comment: Even when I return the value that clean_number gives me I get no result, before the if statement. The input is being passed correctly because when I make the clean_number statement just return phoneNumber, the script works.

Comment: Are you calling the script via osascript?

What happens if you ask for just "input", before anything happens?

Comment: Hmm, when I run it the way you showed it seems to work, Im not sure what automator is doing, I eliminated the parameters like you said but it still seems to return nothing

Comment: Since the problem doesn't seem to be with the script, but with the way Automator is calling the script, it may be helpful to edit your question to describe that part more.

Comment: Also when I return input before anything happens it returns the correct input

Comment: What exactly is being returned? Is it exactly the input you expect, or is there a comma or a space following it?  What happens if you say "return length input" or, a line down, "return length originalText"?

Answer (score 0):

I inserted a log statement, into the run handler, so  I could get some output by *Console.app* (All messages) as to what happened when I ran the service, I did hit the play button of the service first, and then Automator told me, that I had to insert a "Fetch specified Text" action, so that it had something to work with during dry runs. I also added a set phoneNumber to phoneNumber as text inside the formatting handler. -I also used res, instead of assigning to result, because I am unfamiliar with doing that. Anyhow, I got **(XXX)XXX-XXXX** returned back, when I used **(XXX)XXX-XXXX** as input.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set originalText to clean_number(input) as string
    log "here: " & originalText
    if length of originalText is 10 then
        set areaCode to items 1 thru 3 of originalText as string
        set localExchange to items 4 thru 6 of originalText as string
        set phoneNumber to items 7 thru end of originalText as string
        set res to "(" & areaCode & ")" & localExchange & "-" & phoneNumber as string
        log res
        return res
    end if
end run

on clean_number(phoneNumber)
    set phoneNumber to phoneNumber as text
    set newString to {}
    repeat with c in the characters of phoneNumber
        set c to c as text
        if c is not "-" then
            if c is not " " then
                set the end of newString to c
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
    return newString
end clean_number
```

Comment: See my updated answer.  Automator passes input as a list, so you need to work with item 1 of input

Comment: I just coerced the parameter of the format phone number handler to text.

Comment: Seems a little risky.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Please do elaborate what the risk is.

Comment: I don't think it's a big deal or a likely scenario, but if Automator is sending lists of items a later version might decide to send more info (or a whitespace, or a comma, or something) as a part of the list, which would get smeared into the coerced text. Is there an advantage to coercing to text rather than taking the item from the list?

Comment: If the change the format of the input parameter, to say text, which is the most likely change to happen, (that will never happen), then there won't be added any commas or anything. Nowadays, the text item delimiters are private per process, so those aren't a problem anymore anyway. They will really never change the data type of the input parameter because that may potentially break a lot of services and workflows.